# Admob almost stop serving ads on my app. and never send me any policy violation email

Tags: android, admob

**Its been 5 days, admob almost not serving ads on my app** I use to get almost 4000 Impressions a day but now I get only a few Impressions a day,

- 1)My admob is in good standing
- 2)MY app does not block from admob
- 3) I    never received any policy violation from admob for this app
- 4)My    app still live on google play

[image]

Here is logs witch i get when i run my app

```
08-16 17:52:24.597 7713-7713/com.ameerhamza.animatedgiflivewallpapers W/Ads: Not retrying to fetch app settings
08-16 17:52:24.637 7713-7780/com.ameerhamza.animatedgiflivewallpapers W/Ads: Invoke Firebase method getInstance error.
08-16 17:52:24.637 7713-7780/com.ameerhamza.animatedgiflivewallpapers W/Ads: The Google Mobile Ads SDK will not integrate with Firebase. Admob/Firebase integration requires the latest Firebase SDK jar, but Firebase SDK is either missing or out of date
08-16 17:52:24.687 7713-7713/com.ameerhamza.animatedgiflivewallpapers W/Ads: Not retrying to fetch app settings
08-16 17:52:24.727 7713-7713/com.ameerhamza.animatedgiflivewallpapers W/Ads: Not retrying to fetch app settings
08-16 17:52:24.988 7713-7820/com.ameerhamza.animatedgiflivewallpapers W/Ads: Update ad debug logging enablement as false
08-16 17:52:24.988 7713-7776/com.ameerhamza.animatedgiflivewallpapers W/Ads: Update ad debug logging enablement as false
08-16 17:52:25.028 7713-7823/com.ameerhamza.animatedgiflivewallpapers W/Ads: Update ad debug logging enablement as false
08-16 17:52:25.929 27415-5203/? W/Ads: Received error HTTP response code: 403
08-16 17:52:25.929 7713-7727/com.ameerhamza.animatedgiflivewallpapers W/Ads: There was a problem getting an ad response. ErrorCode: 0
08-16 17:52:25.929 7713-7713/com.ameerhamza.animatedgiflivewallpapers W/Ads: Failed to load ad: 0
08-16 17:52:26.029 7713-7780/com.ameerhamza.animatedgiflivewallpapers W/Ads: Fail to instantiate adapter com.google.DummyAdapter
                                                                             android.os.RemoteException
                                                                                 at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzxm.zzbp(Unknown Source)
                                                                                 at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzxm.zzbo(Unknown Source)
                                                                                 at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzxm.zzbm(Unknown Source)
                                                                                 at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzxo.dispatchTransaction(Unknown Source)
                                                                                 at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzek.onTransact(Unknown Source)
                                                                                 at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:395)
                                                                                 at nb.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_adsdynamite@12874007@12.8.74 (020304-204998136):10)
                                                                                 at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.mediation.client.d.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_adsdynamite@12874007@12.8.74 (020304-204998136):5)
                                                                                 at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.reward.a.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_adsdynamite@12874007@12.8.74 (020304-204998136):15)
                                                                                 at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.reward.mediation.j.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_adsdynamite@12874007@12.8.74 (020304-204998136):27)
                                                                                 at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.util.b.run(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_adsdynamite@12874007@12.8.74 (020304-204998136):4)
                                                                                 at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:422)
                                                                                 at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
                                                                                 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
                                                                                 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
                                                                                 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
08-16 17:52:26.029 7713-7713/com.ameerhamza.animatedgiflivewallpapers W/Ads: Failed to load ad: 3
08-16 17:52:26.079 7713-7713/com.ameerhamza.animatedgiflivewallpapers W/Ads: Failed to load ad: 3
```

MY build.gradle

```
  implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:15.0.0'
```

and

```
 classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.0'
```

This is how i made ad requst in my mainActivty

```
 private void showPersonalizedAds() {
        ConsentInformation.getInstance(this)
                .setConsentStatus(ConsentStatus.PERSONALIZED);
        MobileAds.initialize(this, "ca-app-pub-5168564707064012~7233193271");
        mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this);
        mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-5168564707064012/2661778477");
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().addTestDevice(DEVICE_ID).build();
        mInterstitialAd.loadAd(adRequest);
        mInterstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAdClosed() {
                // Load the next interstitial.
                mInterstitialAd.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().addTestDevice(DEVICE_ID).build());
            }

            @Override
            public void onAdFailedToLoad(int i) {
                super.onAdFailedToLoad(i);
                Log.d(TAG, "ad not loaded" + i);
            }
        });


        mRewardedVideoAd = MobileAds.getRewardedVideoAdInstance(MainActivity.this);
        mRewardedVideoAd.loadAd("ca-app-pub-5168564707064012/4067252078", new AdRequest.Builder().build());

        AdView mAdView = findViewById(R.id.adView);
        mAdView.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().addTestDevice(DEVICE_ID).build());

    }
```

Comment: Hello i have same problem you get the solution ?

Comment: yas i fix it you can follow my video about it https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N0fXfaD7ZJY&t=150s